# node.js-Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: android, node.js

When I run the code, it shows "User was registered successfully", but followed with "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined". 
I try to fix the error, but failed. I think it may be some error in userRecord, but I checked many times and can't find what's the problem.

Here is my code:

```
var app = require('express')();

var http = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var userAccountRequests = (io) =>{
  io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
    console.log(`Client ${socket.id} is connected`);

    detectDisconnection(socket,io);
    registerUser(socket,io);

  });
};
```

I think there may be some error here. It can show the "successfully" message, but I think I have defined email.

```
function registerUser(socket,io){
  socket.on('userData',(data)=>{
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email:data.email,
      displayname:data.userName,
      password:data.password
    })
    .then((userRecord)=>{
      console.log('User was registered successfully');
      var db = admin.database();
      var ref = db.ref('users');
      var userRef = ref.child(encodeEmail(data.email));
      var data = {
        data:admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
      };
      userRef.ser({
        email:data.email,
        userName:data.userName,
        dataJoined:date,
        hasLoggedIn:false
      });

      //send message to Client
      Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((id)=>{
        if(id == socket.id){
          var message = {
            text:'Success'
          }
          io.to(id).emit('message',{message});
        }
      });
    }).catch((error)=>{
      Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((id)=>{
        console.log(error.message);
        if(id == socket.id){
          var message = {
            text:error.message
          }
          io.to(id).emit('message',{message});
        }
      });

    });

  });
}

function detectDisconnection(socket,io){
  socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
    console.log('Client has disconnected');
  });
}

function encodeEmail(email) {
  return email.replace('.',',');

}

module.exports = {
  userAccountRequests
}
```

Comment: NM, I rescind this comment, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' object is only active within the function in 'on', this code:

```
  socket.on('userData',(data)=>{
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email:data.email,
      displayname:data.userName,
      password:data.password
    })
```

At the end of this function, 'data' is no longer defined.  The 'then' that follows is using 'userRecord' instead.

You should change your 'data' references to 'userRecord', like this:

```
function registerUser(socket,io){
  socket.on('userData',(data)=>{
    admin.auth().createUser({
      email:data.email,
      displayname:data.userName,
      password:data.password
    })
    .then((userRecord)=>{
      console.log('User was registered successfully');
      var db = admin.database();
      var ref = db.ref('users');
      var userRef = ref.child(encodeEmail(userRecord.email));
// not sure what this is about
      var data = {
        data:admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
      };
      userRef.ser({
        email:userRecord.email,
        userName:userRecord.userName,
        dataJoined:date,
        hasLoggedIn:false
      });

      //send message to Client
      Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((id)=>{
        if(id == socket.id){
          var message = {
            text:'Success'
          }
          io.to(id).emit('message',{message});
        }
      });
    }).catch((error)=>{
```